# Get CGPoint x points in front of node

Tags: sprite-kit, trigonometry, skspritenode, cgpoint

I am working on a game in sprite kit and have been trying to get a point in front of a node. I've been reading up on trigonometry but have not been able to do it.

**The problem**: Get a CGPoint x units in front of an SKSpriteNode, relative to zRotation. See the illustration here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGZ51.png

I have understood that i can use the adjacent and opposite lengths in the triangle to calculate the distance of the hypotenuse (and that the hypotenuse is a vector?). However, i've failed to understand how to get this vector relative to current zPosition and how to get a point from the vector.

I would be grateful if anyone can provide some sample code or point me in a direction where i can find more info.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after trying some more and here's how i did it:

```
- (CGVector)convertAngleToVector:(CGFloat)radians {
    CGVector vector;
    vector.dx = cos(radians) * 40;
    vector.dy = sin(radians) * 40;
    return vector;
}
```

I call the method with the sprites zRotation which gives me a vector. The number 40 decides how long the vector is. Then i just added the vector to the current position.